# Why Removing item from list in this way is impossible?

Tags: list, c#-4.0

I have a problem that as i try to remove item from any list in following way i am unable to do that ... why is that so the error is **"use of unassigned local variable"** where is it is assigned as shown below:

```
  public void RemoveFrmList(int ProdId)
        {
            int _index;
            foreach (Products item in BoughtItems)
            {
                if (item.ProductID == ProdId)
                {
                   _index = BoughtItems.IndexOf(item);
                }

            }
            BoughtItems.RemoveAt(_index);
        }
```

what can be done to remove this error?

Comment: You are mutating the list over which you are iterating.  You can't do that.

Comment: Think about what happens if `ProdId` doesn't exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_index` is unassigned until you go in the loop. But if `BoughtItems` has no `Product` items, you will have a unnassigned variable `_index`. Or maybe you will never get an item with `item.ProductID == ProdID`.

So in other words:

```
int _index;
foreach (Products item in BoughtItems)
{
   //Code here is not executed during runtime for reasons stated above.
}
BoughtItems.RemoveAt(_index); //error here because _index was not assigned!
```

To fix it, you could do something like

```
int _index = -1;
foreach (...)
{
   //...
}
if (_index != -1){
   BoughtItems.RemoveAt(_index);
}
else
{
  //handle case if needed
}
```

Comment: `_index` is an `int`, a value type. It will default to `0`, as it _can't_ have a `null` value.

Answer (score 2):

the code inside the if statement does not necessarily occur. Initialize _index to -1 or some "not found" indicating value and the error should go away.

Answer (score 2):

What is `BoughtItems` ? If it's `List<T>` just use [RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx)

```
public void RemoveFrmList(int ProdId)
{
    BoughtItems.RemoveAll( item => item.ProductID == ProdId );
}
```

Slightly offtopic but why is RemoveFrmLis missing the o? It just hurts readability. Use the full word.